# Gambler Ruin Probability

Tags: probability

I read the document about sequential testing written by Evan Miller on the website (https://www.evanmiller.org/sequential-ab-testing.html). In his document, he mentioned that the probability of the gambler with d tokens at the beginning will ruin after exactly n coin flips is (assume the probability of the gambler wins under 0.5 each time)
$$
r_{n,d} = \frac{d}{n}{n \choose (n+d)/2}{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}^n
$$
I tried to figure out this probability on my own. If the gambler loses after exactly n coin flips, the gambler must lose the game at the $n^{th}$ game. Assume that the gambler wins A games in total and loses B games in total, we could figure out
$A=\frac{n-d}{2}$, $B=\frac{n+d}{2}$.The gambler should lose B-1 games in the first n-1 games and lose the $n^{th}$ game.
Hence, the probability of the gambler with d tokens at the beginning will ruin after exactly n coin flips is
$$
P(The\;gambler\;ruins\;after\;exactly\;n\;coin\;flips)=P(The\;gambler\;loses\;B-1\;games\;before\;n-1\;coin\;flips)\times P(The\;gambler\;loses\;at\;the\;n^{th}\;game)
$$
As in the $n^{th}$ game, the gambler must lose, the probability of the gambler loses the $n^{th}$ game should be 1. Hence, the probability of the gambler ruins after exactly n coin flips is equal to the probability of the gambler loses B-1 games before n-1 coin flips. Therefore, the probability is
$$
P(the\;gambler\;wins\;after\;exactly\;n\;coin\;flips)={n-1 \choose (n+d)/2-1}\times{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}^{\left(\frac{n+d}{2}-1\right)}\times{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}^{(n-1)-\left(\frac{n+d}{2}-1\right)}
={n-1 \choose (n+d)/2-1}\times{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}^{\left(n-1\right)}
=\frac{n+d}{n}\times{n \choose (n+d)/2}\times{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}^n
$$
As we can see, the result which I calculated is different from the Evan showed in his document. Did I make any mistakes in the probability calculation?